# GDM unable to start on RaspberryPi 4 with Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, gdm

I am trying to use Ubuntu Server 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4.
I have installed the packages ubuntu-desktop-minimal and rebooted but I get no login screen on the Pi only a blinking dash.

I have also tried the ubuntu-desktop-raspi and ubuntu-desktop packages to no avail.

I have also tried editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncommenting `WaylandEnable=false` to try without Wayland but the result was the same.

During boot the screen appears to work ok I get the boot logs appearing on my monitor etc.

GDM seems to be running but showing this in the log:

```
Jun 20 16:58:18 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1232]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1232]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=116) by (uid=0)
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1227 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1227 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1221]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1221]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1221]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=116) by (uid=0)
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1217 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1217 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1211]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1211]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1211]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=116) by (uid=0)
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1207 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1207 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1200]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1200]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1200]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=116) by (uid=0)
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1187 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1187 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1177]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:17 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1177]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jun 20 16:58:16 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1177]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=116) by (uid=0)
Jun 20 16:58:16 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1165 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:16 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:58:16 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: Child process -1165 was already dead.
Jun 20 16:58:16 SYKIOSKPI gdm3[1086]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jun 20 16:57:43 SYKIOSKPI gdm-launch-environment][1149]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=116) by (uid=0)
Jun 20 16:57:33 SYKIOSKPI systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Jun 20 16:57:33 SYKIOSKPI systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
```

I've enabled debug in GDM and ran it again, log can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ze8PWHEd

This is the GDM X server log: https://pastebin.com/c4uTZRVn

Unsure what to try next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/128282/111226) I added `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` into `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and it now works.

I would accept any answer that can explain what this means and if there's a better alternative, this setting works but I do not know what it does.